# Relative distance between neurons

Tags: geometry, approximation, volume, fermi-problems

I am trying to work out the relative distance between neurons in the human brain if the brain was scaled up to the size of the earth.

So if each neuron was 0.0001mm apart (just a guess), would that translate to 1m? or 10m? or more or less?

Given that the brain is approx. 1400cm3 in volume and there are about 100b neurons, is there an easy way to figure out this relative distance assuming that each neuron is equally spaced?

Comment: This reminds me of what is frequently called Fermi problems:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem

Comment: @KonKan I see that you have created ([tag:fermi-problems]) tag. It might be useful to create also [tag-wiki or at least tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/fermi-problems/info). It might help other users to use the tag correctly. Another reason is that the tags used on only one question are [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) after certain time [unless they have tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700).

Comment: @Martin Sleziak: thank you for the info on that. I will consider your advise.